# Always boots into 2D mode

Tags: unity, 12.04, graphics

I have `Ubuntu 12.04` and initially choosing normal Ubuntu at login gave me `Ubuntu 3D`. However, for a few days now, selecting either `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu 2D` gives me `2D`:

```
~$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION 
ubuntu-2d
```

Answer (score 1):

Your graphic card is not supporting the 3d mode.

I may be a trouble with your graphic drivers. It happens often after a kernel update. (even more if it's an ati or nvidia graphic card)

You can confirm this with this command : glxinfo | grep rendering
(install glxinfo if you don't have it)

You may need to reinstall your graphic driver if it's nvidia or ati.

Leave me a comment if you need more explanations.

Comment: I was using the ATI proprietary driver (ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver), installed from additional drivers. I uninstalled it, booted in normal mode, and had no launchers or system bar. Then I went into 2D mode, and installed it again. This left me with the same behviour of 2d mode regardless which session I logged in as.

Comment: have you confirmed that your fglrx driver is used ? type this on a terminal and check that mesa is not mentionend : fglrxinfo

Answer (score 1):

If you have a laptop with hybrid graphics it may also arise the issue you experience. Then you might want to look at the [Bumblebee project](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) which enables your hybrid graphics to work correctly.